# component's render() is not getting invoked after updating mobx store value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

Updating store before fetching data from server, works fine.. But after fetching data from from server and updating store, render() method not getting invoked
[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHw1B.png)

```
 @action
      static getPartner(partnerParams) {
         store.invitationDetails.invitingOrgPartnerName = ""; // here render() is getting invoked
        fetchPartner(partnerParams)
          .then((data) => data.json())
          .then(function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
              if (result.alreadyPartner) {
                  runInAction(() => {
                     store.invitationDetails.invitingOrgPartnerName = result.partnerName;   // here render() is NOT getting invoked      
                 }); 
              }
            }
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.info("Failed getting partners", e);
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: One of the reason for your error]

[Mobx works perfectly in most of the cases but not always](https://doc.ebichu.cc/mobx/best/pitfalls.html)

You should use **extendObservable**
Please follow this [ExtendObservable](https://doc.ebichu.cc/mobx/refguide/extend-observable.html)